# How to set visibility for an Actionbar menu item?

Tags: android

I tried to hide item and group with below code it is not working, can someone please help me with this code. I tried for item and group both not working.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.login);

    // show the button when some condition is true
    if (true) {
        shareItem.setVisible(false);
    }

    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.common_menu, false);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this following code:
  call this function whereever you want `hideItem()`

```
  private void hideItem()
    {

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_adduser).setVisible(false);
    }
```